# How to set user's selection into my array and randomly choose element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make my program to play audio list at different duration time. From audio list element 4, the duration and will depend on user's selection and play every element in the range of 4 to 8 for the first round. (so the first round, the program will play element 4, 5,...,8.)

Another question is to randomly select between element 4 to 8 from the audio list and play but the duration will be the same from user's selection.

My thinking is to use if statement for i = 4, and do the for loop. If I don't use loop, I can store user input and set it to element's duration. But considering I need to play audio from element 4 to 8, so I think I should use loop, but if I use loop, I can't store user input to my array. Why is this? And how to randomly make code to choose array list from element 4 to 8.

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

```
<select id="numFollowUp" name="numFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Number of follow-up questions</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select id="secFollowUp" name="secFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Second between each question</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

var intro_playList = [{
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "0_silence"
    }, {
        "duration": 500,
        "key": "1_hello"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "2_how_old"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "3_what_did_you_make"
    }, {
        // story_playlist
        "duration": 1000,
        //"duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "4_tell_me_a_story"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        //"duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "5_and_then_what"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "6_why"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "7_tell_me_more"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "8_what_happened_next"
    }];

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

        audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio);

        var i = 0;
        $("#play").on("click", playAudio);

        function playAudio() {
            console.log(i);
            var audioIndex = intro_playList[i++];
            console.log(audioIndex);
            console.log("After " + audioIndex.duration + " seconds play next audio");

            audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
            audioElement.load();
            setTimeout(function() { audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);

            if(i === 4){

                while(i === 4)
                {
                  intro_playList[i].duration = document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000

                audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
                audioElement.load();
                setTimeout(function(){ audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);
                i++;

                if(i === 8) break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not certain what requirement is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fisher-Yates shuffle to create a shuffled (no duplication) sequence for 4-8 as below (pseudo code):

```
for (let i = 4; i > 1; i--) {
    let idx = Math.round(Math.random() * (i - 1));
    let t = songs[3 + i];
    songs[3 + i] = songs[3 + idx];
    songs[3 + idx] = t;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Xihua. But your pseudo code is hard to understand for me. Would you mind explaining more ? Or there's an example?

Comment: You are welcome. You can read more about Fisher-Yates shuffle shuffle from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle.  Actually the most unnatural (somehow weird) part in my code is 3 + x part, the purpose is to avoid shuffling the user pre-selected 4 songs (index #0-3). BTW, "songs" in my code is the array contains all your music to play.